# transport shiny output to another script

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a bit new at coding, but I try to teach myself new stuff all the time. Recently I started using shiny in R because I needed to have user interaction somewhere along my script. However, now that I've build my shiny app (a very basic one, but it works), my problem is that after reading dozens of webpages, tutorials etc, I still don't understand how to add code that will store the results of the user input in the shiny app into a vector / value that I can use in the other R script.

my ui.R scipt:

```
library(shiny)
ui = fluidPage(
radioButtons("Question","Do you want to keep cluster?",
                 c("YES" = 1, "NO" = 0)),
actionButton(inputId= "submit", label="OK")
)
```

my server script

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
observe({
if(input$submit > 0){

  stopApp(input$Question)
}
})
})
```

This app will be run inside a loop in the other R script. It will present the user with the yes/no question for each cluster created by a script that autoclusters large amounts of data.

What I need is to have the 0 and 1 output values to be combined into a vector like answer <-c(answer,"ShinyOutputValue")  after each run of the loop.

Its driving me nuts that I can't get it to work. Please help :)

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable answer in your global environment.

```
assign("answer", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv) # answer <- NULL
```

Then, using functions `get` (or `mget`) you can 'get' the variable `answer` from the global environment to shiny (shiny runs in some random environment) and then using `assign` overwrite it with new values in global environment.

---

```
assign("answer", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv) # answer <- NULL

library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("Question","Do you want to keep cluster?",
               c("YES" = 1, "NO" = 0)),
  actionButton(inputId= "submit", label="OK")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  observe({
    if(input$submit > 0){

      val <- as.numeric(input$Question)
      old_val <- get("answer", envir = .GlobalEnv)
      assign("answer", c(old_val, val), envir = .GlobalEnv)

      stopApp(input$Question)
    }
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)

answer
```

---

You can also create your own environment and save objects in:

```
new_env <- environment()
new_env$number <- 5
new_env$number
get("number", envir = new_env)
assign("n", 1:10, envir = new_env)
new_env$n
```